# How to ignore specific bits in a 32-bit integer

Tags: c++

I am polling a 32-bit register in a motor driver for a value.

Only bits 0-9 are required, the rest need to be ignored.

How do I ignore bits 10-31?

[Image of register bits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX5XP.png)

In order to poll the motor driver for a value, I send the location of the register, which sends back the entire 32-bit number. But I only need bits 0-9 to display.

`Serial.println(sendData(0x35, 0))`

Comment: I'm going to guess this is an arduino project - in either case, the very short sample you have isn't C.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract such bits then you must mask the whole integer with a value that keeps just the bits you are interested in.

This can be done with bitwise AND (`&`) operator, eg:

```
uint32_t value = reg & 0x3ff;
uint32_t value = reg & 0b1111111111; // if you have C++11
```

Comment: I think you need 10 bits for 0..9

Answer (score 1):

You do a bitwise `and` with a number with the last 10 bits set to 1. This will set all the other bits to 0. For example:

```
value = value & ((1<<10) - 1);
```

Or

```
value = value & 0x3FF;
```

Comment: Also last 10 bits set to 1.

Comment: @AviBerger 0x1FF are only 9 bits?

Comment: Right, my mistake. I went back and edited that comment.

Comment: @AviBerger thanks again; I added some more explanation about 0 and 1 bits

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `Serial.println()` I'd go with `Serial.print()`.
You can then just print out the specific bits that you're interested in with a for loop.

```
auto data = sendData(0x35, 0);
for (int i=0; i<=9; ++i)
    Serial.print(data && (1<<i));
```

Any other method will result in extra bits being printed since there's no data structure that holds 10 bits.